# Datatable adding dropdown list column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, dropdown

I am trying to add dropdownlist in a datatable column. I tried different methods. Render returns object to the columns. I attached an image. Please have a look.

[image]

Here is the code that I tried. I found many working example using this code. However, in my case it doesn't work. Don't know where is the trick. Can anyone please help me figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
                    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                                <th>Column 5</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                                <th>Column 5</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>                                                    
            

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function createDropDown() {

        var html = '<select><option value="">Select a Stauts...</option>';
            html += '<option value="0">0</option>';
            html += '</select>';

        return html;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        var counter = 1;

        var times = [
        "12:00 am",
        "1:00 am",
        "2:00 am",
        "3:00 am",
        "4:00 am",
        "5:00 am",
        "6:00 am",
        "7:00 am",
        "8:00 am",
        "9:00 am",
        "10:00 am",
        "11:00 am",
        "12:00 pm",
        "1:00 pm",
        "2:00 pm",
        "3:00 pm",
        "4:00 pm",
        "5:00 pm",
        "6:00 pm",
        "7:00 pm",
        "8:00 pm",
        "9:00 pm",
        "10:00 pm",
        "11:00 pm"
        ];



    var dropDown = createDropDown();

    $('#addRow').on('click', function () {
        t.row.add([

            {
                "render": function (d, t, r) {
                    var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                        "id": r[0] + "start",
                        "value": d
                    });

                    $.each(times, function (k, v) {
                        var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                            "text": v,
                            "value": v
                        });
                        //if (d === v) {
                        //    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                        //}
                        $select.append($option);
                    });

                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                }
            },


             {
                 "render": function (d, t, r) {
                     var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                         "id": r[0] + "start",
                         "value": d
                     });
                     $.each(times, function (k, v) {
                         var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                             "text": v,
                             "value": v
                         });
                         if (d === v) {
                             $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                         }
                         $select.append($option);
                     });
                     return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                 }
             },
            {
                    defaultContent: "",
                    data: "Status",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var dropdown = '';
                            dropdown = '<select class="form-control"><option value="0">Select Status</option></select>';
                       
                        return dropdown;
                    }
            },
            {
                data: null, // "Status"
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return dropDown;
                }
            },
            counter + '.5'
        ]
        ).draw();

        counter++;
    });

    
    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
});

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
                    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                                <th>Column 5</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2</th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                                <th>Column 4</th>
                                <th>Column 5</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>                                                    
            

<script type="text/javascript">

    function createDropDown() {

        var html = '<select><option value="">Select a Stauts...</option>';
            html += '<option value="0">0</option>';
            html += '</select>';

        return html;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        var counter = 1;

        var times = [
        "12:00 am",
        "1:00 am",
        "2:00 am",
        "3:00 am",
        "4:00 am",
        "5:00 am",
        "6:00 am",
        "7:00 am",
        "8:00 am",
        "9:00 am",
        "10:00 am",
        "11:00 am",
        "12:00 pm",
        "1:00 pm",
        "2:00 pm",
        "3:00 pm",
        "4:00 pm",
        "5:00 pm",
        "6:00 pm",
        "7:00 pm",
        "8:00 pm",
        "9:00 pm",
        "10:00 pm",
        "11:00 pm"
        ];



    var dropDown = createDropDown();

    $('#addRow').on('click', function () {
        t.row.add([

            {
                "render": function (d, t, r) {
                    var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                        "id": r[0] + "start",
                        "value": d
                    });

                    $.each(times, function (k, v) {
                        var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                            "text": v,
                            "value": v
                        });
                        //if (d === v) {
                        //    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                        //}
                        $select.append($option);
                    });

                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                }
            },


             {
                 "render": function (d, t, r) {
                     var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                         "id": r[0] + "start",
                         "value": d
                     });
                     $.each(times, function (k, v) {
                         var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                             "text": v,
                             "value": v
                         });
                         if (d === v) {
                             $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                         }
                         $select.append($option);
                     });
                     return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                 }
             },
            {
                    defaultContent: "",
                    data: "Status",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var dropdown = '';
                            dropdown = '<select class="form-control"><option value="0">Select Status</option></select>';
                       
                        return dropdown;
                    }
            },
            {
                data: null, // "Status"
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return dropDown;
                }
            },
            counter + '.5'
        ]
        ).draw();

        counter++;
    });

    
    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
});

</script>
```

Comment: This seems like an issue where the model objects are not being converted to a string, please add more details what is the server-side language you are using to pull data from the database.

Comment: Basically, here I didn't use data from database. Taking data from an array, times.

Comment: If the its an array of json objects it wont work, you need to print the value you need for eg: obj.name etc

Comment: You are trying to use the function provided by the DataTables [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option outside of your DataTable (it's in a JavaScript `click` function, instead). The DataTables render function will therefore not be executed. Instead, JavaScript will simply return the function itself, as the cell data in your new row. This is why you are seeing `[object Object]` in your cells. The `object` here is the render function itself.

Comment: Because your example code does not have any source data, I can't really tell what the end goal is supposed to look like. Can you [edit] the question and clarify what a successful outcome would actually look like? (For example, what would `d` be in `"value": d`, and so on...).

Comment: Thak you andrewjames for your detail explanation. What I want to do is draw a dropdown column with option data from database. Here I simplyfied this code for easy understanding.

Comment: OK, thank you for the comment. The information in your comment is basically the same as the information which is already in the question.